# I2C maximum value of pull-up resistor (explanation)

Tags: i2c, pullup

This is more of mathematical problem, but I think there is an electrotechnical engineer that can help me.

So I was reading about I2C pull-up values in the [Texas Instruments SLVA689 I2C Bus Pullup Resistor Calculation](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva689/slva689.pdf) document and stumbled upon these equations and partial explanation:

[image: Page of formulas from TI SLVA689 I2C Bus Pullup Resistor Calculation]

What I don't understand is where does the yellow marked value of 0.8473 come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you solve the eponential equation for times t1 and t2, i.e. how long it takes for the RC waveform to rise from 0 to 0.3×Vdd, and from 0 to 0.7×Vdd, then you can calculate the time how long it takes for the RC waveform to rise from 0.3×Vdd to 0.7xVdd, then you get ln(0.7)-ln(0.3) and that's 0.8473 and that is the coefficient for the RC rise time from 0.3 to 0.7.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am weak in mathematics and these kind of step skipping confuses me a lot.